Maximum Likelihood Estimation of median for an exponential distribution
Given data x1, ... xn i.i.d. with exponential distribution and unknown parameter λ, determine maximum likelihood estimation of θ given the observed data where theta is the median of the distribution.
Normally, I think these questions are quite straightforward but the whole thing with a seperate parameter λ has sort of thrown me off.
My idea is as follows:
$L(θ | x) = f(x | θ) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} λe^{-λx}$
$logL(θ | x) = nlog(λ) + -λ\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i= nlog(λ) + -λ\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = nlog(λ) + -λ\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i + λx_{n/2} - λθ$
$\frac{d}{dθ}logL(θ | x) = -λ$ => no local maximum and then I checked bounds and theta = 0 seems to maximise the function.
However, the answer is not 0 but $θ = \frac{ln(2)}{λ}$ and I have no idea where I went wrong. I would greatly appreciate any help :)

This is an exercise in using the invariance property of the MLE.  Specifically, if $\hat \lambda$ is the MLE of $\lambda$ for a sample $\boldsymbol X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ where $X_i \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda)$ are iid, then the MLE $\hat \theta$ of a function $g$ of $\lambda$ is equal to $\hat \theta = g(\hat \lambda)$.  So in your case, the median $\theta$ of the exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$ satisfies
$$\frac{1}{2} = \int_{x=0}^\theta \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \, dx = 1 - e^{-\lambda \theta}$$
which implies
$$\theta = g(\lambda) = \frac{\log 2}{\lambda}.$$
Hence if $\hat \lambda$ is the MLE of $\lambda$, then $$\hat \theta = \frac{\log 2}{\hat \lambda}.$$  All that remains is to express this in terms of the sample $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$.

Addendum.  If the invariance property is not used, then you could reparametrize the likelihood in terms of $\theta$ and then maximize that with respect to $\theta$.  In particular, we have
$$\mathcal L(\lambda \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n) \propto \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda e^{-\lambda x_i} \mathbb 1 (x_i > 0) = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda \sum x_i} \mathbb 1 (x_{(1)} > 0).$$
But in terms of $\theta = \log 2/\lambda$, we have
$$\mathcal L(\theta \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \left(\frac{\log 2}{\theta}\right)^n \exp \left(-\frac{\log 2}{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) \mathbb 1 (x_{(1)} > 0).$$
Removing constants of proportionality and taking logarithms, we obtain the log-likelihood
$$\ell(\theta \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n) \propto -n \log \theta - \frac{n \bar x \log 2}{\theta} + \log \mathbb 1 (x_{(1)} > 0),$$
where $n \bar x$ is shorthand for the sample total $\sum x_i$.  For $x_{(1)} > 0$, taking the derivative of $\ell$ shows it has the unique critical point $$\theta = \bar x \log 2,$$ and this is the desired MLE.

Do you know any methods of doing it without the invariance property as we haven't that learned that?

@MichaelWilliams see edits above.
